# DEV C++ Line 69 [Error] name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I've been working on this code for a while and I've made it compile yet it doesn't do what I want it to do.

Here is the problem so you can see what I'm trying to do.

Develop a program that allows solving the following problem: Panamericana S.A. You want to modify and print the information of your 5 employees. For each one the program must read the name, hours of work, the payment base, the age. For example, a typical group of data could be:

- Full payment for employees at least 40 years old
- The average total payment for employees under 45
- The name and total payment for the employee with maximum total payment (It is assumed that there is no tie)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

    struct Empleados{
        char nombre[20];
        char apellido[20];
        double edad;
        float horas;
        float salporhora;
        float imp;
        float salbruto;
        float salneto;
    }emp[2];

int main(){

    int posM = 0, posm = 0;
    float sal=40;
    float impuesto = 200;
    float sa,prom45;
    float mayor = 0, menor = 99999;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"Introduzca nombre del empleado: ";
        cin.getline(emp[i].nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Introduzca Apellido del empleado: ";
        cin.getline(emp[i].apellido,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Introduzca su edad: ";
        cin>>emp[i].edad;
        cout<<"Introduzca sus horas de trabajo: ";
        cin>>emp[i].horas;
        cout<<"Pago por hora: ";
        cin>>emp[i].salporhora;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        sa = emp[i].salbruto * 1.5;
        emp[i].salbruto = sa + (emp[i].horas * emp[i].salporhora);  
        }

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        if (emp[i].salneto > mayor){
            mayor = emp[i].salneto;
            posM = i;
        }
        if (emp[i].salneto < menor){
            menor = emp[i].salneto;
            posm = i;
        }

    }

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){          
        emp[i].imp = emp[i].salbruto * 0.20;
        emp[i].salneto = emp[i].salbruto - emp[i].imp;
    }




        cout<<"NOMBRE"<<"\t "<<"APELLIDO"<<"\t "<<"HORAS"<<"\t "<<"SUELDO"<<"\t "<<"EDAD"<<"\t "<<"TOTAL"<<"\t "<<"IMP%"<<"\t "<<"NETO"<<"\n";
        cout<<emp[i].nombre<<"\t "<<emp[i].apellido<<"\t "<<emp[i].horas<<"\t "<<emp[i].salporhora<<"\t "<<emp[i].edad<<"\t "<<emp[i].salbruto<<"\t "<<emp[i].imp<<"\t "<<emp[i].salneto<<"\n";

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

        if (emp[i].edad >= 40){
            cout<<"Los Pagos totales de los empleados de almenos 40 "<<emp[i].salneto<<"\n";
        }
        if (emp[i].edad < 45){
            prom45 = emp[i].salneto/2;
            cout<<"El Promedio de Los Pagos totales de los empleados de menos de 45 anos "<<prom45<<"\n";
        }
   }
        cout<<"\nEl empleado con mayor salario es: "<<emp[posM].nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Que tiene un salario de: "<<posM<<endl;
        Sleep (5000);
        cout<<"\nGracias Por su Tiempo"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `i` in a few places but their lifetimes & scope are all limited to their respective `for` loops.

But here

```
cout<<emp[i].nombre<<"\t "<<emp[i].apellido<<"\t "<<emp[i].horas<<"\t "<<emp[i].salporhora<<"\t "<<emp[i].edad<<"\t "<<emp[i].salbruto<<"\t "<<emp[i].imp<<"\t "<<emp[i].salneto<<"\n";
```

you are using `i` - but there's no `i` defined in this scope. That's what the error is about.

Perhaps you meant to include inside the `for` loop above?

```
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){          
    emp[i].imp = emp[i].salbruto * 0.20;
    emp[i].salneto = emp[i].salbruto - emp[i].imp;
}
```